# Python: How to manage and kill worker threads that are either stuck or waiting on a timeout...?

Tags: python, multithreading

This has been discussed many, many times, but I still don't have a good grasp on how to best accomplish this.

Suppose I have two threads: a main app thread and a worker thread. The main app thread (say it's a WXWidgets GUI thread, or a thread that is looping and accepting user input at the console) could have a reason to stop the worker thread - the user's closing the application, a stop button was clicked, some error occurred in the main thread, whatever.

Commonly suggested is to setup a flag that the thread checks frequently to determine whether to exit. I have two problems with the suggested ways to approach this, however:

First, writing constant checks of a flag into my code makes my code really ugly, and it's very, very prone to problems due to the huge amount of code duplication. Take this example:

```
def WorkerThread():

    while (True):
        doOp1() # assume this takes say 100ms.
        if (exitThread == True): 
            safelyEnd()
            return
        doOp2() # this one also takes some time, say 200ms
        if (exitThread == True): 
            safelyEnd()
            return
        if (somethingIsTrue == True):
            doSomethingImportant()
            if (exitThread == True): return
            doSomethingElse()
            if (exitThread == True): return 
        doOp3() # this blocks for an indeterminate amount of time - say, it's waiting on a network respond
        if (exitThread == True): 
            safelyEnd()
            return
        doOp4() # this is doing some math
        if (exitThread == True): 
            safelyEnd()
            return
        doOp5() # This calls a buggy library that might block forever.  We need a way to detect this and kill this thread if it's stuck for long enough...
        saveSomethingToDisk() # might block while the disk spins up, or while a network share is accessed...whatever
        if (exitThread == True): 
            safelyEnd()
            return


def safelyEnd():
    cleanupAnyUnfinishedBusiness() # do whatever is needed to get things to a workable state even if something was interrupted
    writeWhatWeHaveToDisk() # it's OK to wait for this since it's so important
```

If I add more code or change code, I have to make sure I'm adding those check blocks all over the place. If my worker thread is a very lengthy thread, I could easily have tens or even hundreds of those checks. Very cumbersome.

Think of the other problems. If doOp4() does accidentally deadlock, my app will spin forever and never exit. Not a good user experience!

Using daemon threads isn't really a good option either because it denies me the opportunity to execute the `safelyEnd()` code. This code might be important - flushing disk buffers, writing log data for debugging purposes, etc.

Second, my code might call functions that block where I don't have the opportunity to check frequently. Let's say this function exists but it's in code that I don't have access to - say part of a library:

```
def doOp4():
    time.sleep(60) # imagine that this is a network thread, that waits for 60 seconds for a reply before returning.
```

If that timeout is 60 seconds, even if my main thread gives the signal for the thread to end, it still might sit there for 60 seconds, when it would be perfectly reasonable for it to just stop waiting for a network response and exit. If that code is part of a library I didn't write, however, I have no control over how that works.

Even if I did write the code for a network check, I'd basically have to refactor it so that rather than waiting 60 seconds, it loops 60 times and waits 1 second before checking the exit thread! Again, very messy!

The upshot of all of this, is it feels like a good way to be able to implement this easily would be to somehow cause an exception on a specific thread. If I could do that, I could wrap the entire worker thread's code in a try block, and put the `safelyEnd()` code in the exception handler, or even a `finally` block.

Is there a way to either accomplish this, or refactor this code with a different technique that will make things work? The thing is, ideally, when the user requests a quit, we want to make them wait the minimum possible amount. It seems that there has to be a simple way to accomplish this, as this is a very common thing in apps!

Most of the thread communication objects don't allow for this type of setup. They might allow for a cleaner way to have an exit flag, but it still doesn't eliminate the need to constantly check that exit flag, and it still won't deal with the thread blocking because of an external call or because it's simply in a busy loop.

The biggest thing for me is really that if I have a long worker thread procedure I have to litter it with hundreds of checks of the flag. This just seems way too messy and doesn't feel like it's very good coding practice. There has to be a better way...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no sane way to kill threads - but you already knew that.  That you don't **like** it is, sadly, irrelevant ;-)

Comment: One solution is to restructure your thread function so that it runs a simple loop around, e.g., a state machine, so you only have to write the check once, at the state machine's transition loop, rather than once per inlined implicit state body.

Comment: BTW, "exceptions" in Python are synchronous:  nothing in CPython knows an exception has occurred until the eval loop goes around & notices that some code has **requested** an exception be raised.  That's why your easy workaround can't be done.  You'd need something like OS-level asynchronous signals instead.  But the mix of signals and threads and OS quirks make that a nightmare.  It's remarkable that KeyboardInterrupt works, and that's about the practical limit on what CPython can do.

Answer (score 4):

First, you *can* make this a lot less verbose and repetitive by using an exception, without needing the ability to raise exceptions into the thread from outside, or any other new tricks or language features:

```
def WorkerThread():
    class ExitThreadError(Exception):
        pass
    def CheckEnd():
        if exitThread:
            raise ExitThreadError()

    try:
        while True:
            doOp1() # assume this takes say 100ms.
            CheckEnd()
            doOp2() # this one also takes some time, say 200ms
            CheckEnd()
            # etc.
    except ExitThreadError:
        safelyEnd()
```

Note that you really ought to be guarding `exitThread` with a `Lock` or `Condition`—which is another good reason to wrap up the check, so you only need to fix that in one place.

Anyway, I've taken out some excessive parentheses, `== True` checks, etc. that added nothing to the code; hopefully you can still see how it's equivalent to the original.

---

You can take this even farther by restructuring your function into a simple state machine; then you don't even need an exception. I'll show a ridiculously trivial example, where every state always implicitly transitions to the next state no matter what. For this case, the refactor is obviously reasonable; whether it's reasonable for your real code, only you can really tell.

```
def WorkerThread():
    states = (doOp1, doOp2, doOp3, doOp4, doOp5)
    current = 0
    while not exitThread:
        states[current]()
        current += 1
    safelyEnd()
```

---

Neither of these does anything to help you interrupt in the middle of one of your steps.

If you have some function that takes 60 seconds and there's not a damn thing you can do about it, then there's no way to cancel your thread during those 60 seconds and there's not a damn thing you can do about it. That's just the way it is.

But usually, things that take 60 seconds are really doing something like blocking on a `select`, and there *is* something you can do about that—create a pipe, stick its read end in the `select`, and write on the other end to wake up the thread.

Or, in you're feeling hacky, often just closing/deleting/etc. a file or other object that the function is waiting on/processing/otherwise using will often guarantee that it fails quickly with an exception. Of course sometimes it guarantees a segfault, or corrupted data, or a 50% chance of exiting and a 50% chance of hanging forever, or… So, even if you can't *control* that `doOp4` function, you'd better be able to analyze its source and/or whitebox test it.

If worst comes to worst, then yes, you do have to either change that one 60-second timeout into 60 1-second timeouts. But usually it won't come to that.

---

Finally, if you really *do* need to be able to kill a thread, don't use a thread, use a child process. Those are killable.

Just make sure that your process is always in a state where it's safe to kill it—or, if you only care about Unix, use a USR signal and mask it out when the process isn't in a safe-to-kill state.

But if it's not safe to kill your process in the middle of that 60-second `doOp4` call, this isn't really going to help you, because you still won't be able to kill it during those 60 seconds.

In some cases, you can have the child process arrange for the parent to clean up for it if it gets killed unexpectedly, or even arrange for it to be cleaned up on the next run (e.g., think of a typical database journal).

But ultimately, what you're asking for is ultimately a contradiction: You want to hard-kill a thread without giving it a chance to finish what it's doing, but you want to guarantee that it finishes what it's doing, and you don't want to rewrite the code to make that possible. So, you need to rethink your design so that it requires something that isn't impossible.

Comment: I have to point out that that `if exitThread == True:` is making me itchy, but in all seriousness great post.

Comment: @roippi: Yes, I agree. I was trying to avoid making any more changes to the OP's code than necessary, but you can see I didn't succeed at that (my fingers removed those excessive parentheses without me even realizing it…), but I might as well change that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind your code running about ten times slower, you can use the `Thread2` class implemented below. An example follows that shows how calling the new `stop` method should kill the thread on the next bytecode instruction. Implementing a cleanup system is left as an exercise for the reader to accomplish.

```
import threading
import sys

class StopThread(StopIteration): pass

threading.SystemExit = SystemExit, StopThread

class Thread2(threading.Thread):

    def stop(self):
        self.__stop = True

    def _bootstrap(self):
        if threading._trace_hook is not None:
            raise ValueError('Cannot run thread with tracing!')
        self.__stop = False
        sys.settrace(self.__trace)
        super()._bootstrap()

    def __trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if self.__stop:
            raise StopThread()
        return self.__trace


class Thread3(threading.Thread):

    def _bootstrap(self, stop_thread=False):
        def stop():
            nonlocal stop_thread
            stop_thread = True
        self.stop = stop

        def tracer(*_):
            if stop_thread:
                raise StopThread()
            return tracer
        sys.settrace(tracer)
        super()._bootstrap()

################################################################################

import time

def main():
    test = Thread2(target=printer)
    test.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    test.stop()
    test.join()

def printer():
    while True:
        print(time.time() % 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `Thread3` class appears to run code approximately 33% faster than the `Thread2` class.